# See object changes in post_save in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am curious if there is a way to see what has changed on an object after saving it using the Django Rest Framework.  I have some special behavior I need to check if a field has been changed from its original value that I was hoping to handle using the `post_save` on `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`.

My first thought was to check using `pre_save` but it seems that `pre_save`'s object argument already has the changes applied to it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**OLD ANSWER for django rest framework version 2.3.12:**

To check if anything has changed on update, you will have to compare the unchanged model instance which is self.object with the changed model instance which is serializer.object.

The object argument which is passed to the pre_save method is the serializer.object which is not yet saved in the database with the new changes.

The unchanged model instance is the self.object which has been fetched from the database using self.get_object_or_none(). Compare it with the obj argument in the pre_save method.

```
def pre_save(self,obj):
    unchanged_instance = self.object
    changed_instance = obj
    ..... # comparison code
```

**NEW ANSWER for django rest framework 3.3:**

`pre_save` and `post_save` are no longer valid.

Now you can place any pre save or post save logic in [`perform_update`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) method. For example:

```
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    # NOTE: serializer.instance gets updated after calling save
    # if you want to use the old_obj after saving the serializer you should
    # use self.get_object() to get the old instance. 
    # other wise serializer.instance would do fine
    old_obj = self.get_object()
    new_data_dict = serializer.validated_data
    # pre save logic
    if old_obj.name != new_data_dict['name']:
        do_something
    .....
    new_obj = serializer.save()
    # post save logic
    ......
```

Comment: This does not appear to work. ``self.object`` and ``obj`` are identical copies. I posted a new value and both ``self.object`` and ``obj`` show the same value, which should not be the case, why?

Comment: Agree, this does NOT work, at least in 2.4.  In `post_save`:

(Pdb) id(self.presave_self_object)
140606733535888
(Pdb) id(self.presave_obj)
140606733535888
(Pdb) id(obj)
140606733535888
(Pdb) id(self.object)
140606733535888

Comment: For DRF 3.x I would override update() as there is already a call to self.get_object()

Comment: The newly edited version for Django REST Framework 3.3 works (i.e. Use on `perform_update`).  Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you use `serializer.instance` instead of `self.get_object()`?

Comment: @Nick `serializer.instance` worked equally well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with help from [model_utils FieldTracker](http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker).  You can install a tracker on the relevant model, then in `pre_save` (by `post_save` it's too late) you can do this:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    if hasattr(obj, 'tracker'):
        self.changed_fields = obj.tracker.changed()
    else:
        self.changed_fields = None
```

`changed_fields` will look like this: `{'is_public': False, 'desc': None}`