# In django rest framework 3.0+, how to check object differences on update?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can you check on  save if the object was changed by the user? I.e. if any differences from the original database object were introduced. Before it was possible with `pre_save()` ([See object changes in post_save in django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249586/see-object-changes-in-post-save-in-django-rest-framework)), but now that was replaced with `perform_update`, which no longer holds both objects (original and modified) for comparison.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Django REST Framework 3, [`pre_save` was replaced with `perform_update`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#changes-to-prepost-save-hooks), which only takes the serializer as an argument (instead of the object itself).

You can access the validated data that was passed into the request using [the `.validated_data` attribute](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#deserializing-objects) on the serializer. This is the [recommended replacement for `.object`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#use-validated_data-instead-of-object), and should allow you to determine what the differences are.

```
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    original_object = self.get_object() # or (the private attribute) serializer.instance
    changes = serializer.validated_data

    serializer.save(attr=changed_value) # pass arguments into `save` to override changes
```

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I solved in a similar way: `changes = serializer.save()`