# clean django api in serilizer

Tags: django-rest-framework

i write a django api i would like to know if reminder field changed then the Appointment model object save current user.
i used this link 
[See object changes in post_save in django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249586/see-object-changes-in-post-save-in-django-rest-framework)
and write this code

```
class AppointmentBackOfficeViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                                   mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    model = Appointment
    read_serializer_class = AppointmentSerializer
    write_serializer_class = AppointmentCreateSerializer
    reminder_change = False

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        if 'reminder' in serializer.validated_data:
            self.reminder_change = True
        serializer.save()

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AppointmentBackOfficeViewSet, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.user = request.user
        if self.reminder_change:
            instance.reminder_user = request.user
        instance.save()
        res = self.write_serializer_class(instance).data
        return Response(res)

    class AppointmentCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        exclude = ['created_time', 'modified_time']
```

is there a way to write this code clearer than this :
dont use self.reminder_change class field is there better way?
may be move this lines to serializer??(in serializer dont access to request.user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed unecessary fields and **update** method:

```
class AppointmentBackOfficeViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                                   mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    model = Appointment
    read_serializer_class = AppointmentSerializer
    write_serializer_class = AppointmentCreateSerializer

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        # Here you can set attributes directly to the serializer update method
        # It's like setting attribute directly to the updating model

        # Check that reminder has been changed
        reminder = serializer.validated_data.get('reminder')

        if reminder and reminder != instance.reminder: # Reminder is different
            serializer.save(user=self.request.user,
                            reminder_user=self.request.user)
        else:
            serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

This solution will work depending on what type of reminder field is.

If it's String or Integer it will be ok. Problem is that if it's object. Viewset will raise error because serializer reminder field would be integer but instance.reminder would be instance of the reminder object so keep this in mind.